# Saving a particular sheet in a folder

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to save a particular sheet in a folder called as "DD".

I have the following code running. it saves the sheet and stores in the path , but not in a particular folder.

Could anyone help how I can do this.

```
Sub save()

Dim myWorksheets() As String
Dim newWB As Workbook
Dim CurrWB As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim path1, Path2 As String
path1 = ThisWorkbook.Path
Path2 = path1 & "\DD"
Set CurrWB = ThisWorkbook
myWorksheets = Split("Report", ",")
For i = LBound(myWorksheets) To UBound(myWorksheets)
    Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
    CurrWB.Sheets(Trim(myWorksheets(i))).Copy Before:=newWB.Sheets(1)
    newWB.SaveAs filename:=Path2 & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd") & myWorksheets(i) & ".xlsx"
    newWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Introduce yourself to the `Immediate Pane` (Ctrl-G) in the VBE. You can type `? Path2 & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd") & myWorksheets(i) & ".xlsx"` to have it show you the exact path\filename you're attempting to use, and a careful reading through it would have shown you the error. Nothing implicitly wrong with your question, but you'd have your answer with less head-banging and without the time spent writing up a post and waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a backslash here:

```
Path2 = path1 & "\DD\"
```

Comment: Is it also, possible I can save it under CW instead of Date with year ?

Comment: newWB.SaveAs filename:=Path2 & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd") & myWorksheets(i) & ".xlsx"
 here I have the files saved under the date and time, instead I would like to have it as calendar week

Comment: @Jenny `Format(Now(), "ww")`